# How to return value from ionic4 storage or fat arrow?

Tags: typescript, ionic4

I'm creating ionic 4 angular app, and using ionic 4 storage. after that 
i'm set and get key value pair.now when i'm get key value ionic storage, i need to assign value to some variable and return some variable .Below code i'm using

```
//set key value pair
setId(){
this.storage.set('Id',this.id);

//get key value pair
getId(){
this.storage.get('Id').then((val)=>{
console.log('Id is:',val);

some_variable=val;
});
```

I need to return this some_variable.

```
//Like that
getId(){
this.storage.get('Id').then((val)=>{
console.log('Id is:',val);

return some_variable=val;
});
```

I know that i'm wrong. how to achieved this return functionality in ionic storage get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot a `return` in your `getId()` - function

```
getId(){
  return this.storage.get('Id').then((val)=>{
    console.log('Id is:',val);
    return val;
});
```

Hint: always write the expected return type to your function. So Your IDE can complain, if you're missing a return.

```
getId(): Promise<any> {
  return this.storage.get('Id').then((val)=>{
    console.log('Id is:',val);
    return val;
});
```

Now you can get your value by calling your function like this:

```
this.getId().then(val => {
  console.log('Here is your value.', val);
})
```

Comment: Sir when i called getId() function it will return whole function body......like    getId(): Promise<any> {
  return this.storage.get('Id').then((val)=>{
    console.log('Id is:',val);
    return val;
});

Comment: How did you call it? getId() is **async**. So if you call it like "getId().then(result => { ...});" you should be able to access your value

Comment: i had created one service page and written getId() inside service page and use into another page.  i called getId() into another page -----Like---- this.id=this.service.getId();

Comment: Like a said, you cannot call `getId()` like you call it, because it is **ASYNC** I have updated my answer to show you how to correctly call it..

Comment: Thank you sir, you are save my entire day and night time. i love ur knowledge.